# VBA Macro to set hyperlinks from info within the file

Tags: excel, vba, url, hyperlink

Have an excel workbook that has many hyperlinks to university websites, but many of the hyperlinks link to where they shouldn't and often don't change properly for some reason. Have isolated all of the URLs that they should lead to in a range within my sheet and want to set them into the hyperlink. Can't really use the hyperlink formula because it requires the reference cells and the file needs to uploaded in a way where the references can't exist at all, so am trying to use the Hyperlinks.add function in VBA, but I cant seem to get it to change the address or text to select based on what cell its currently linking. Have tried to set them as ranges but they seem to refuse. Would it be possible to get it to check individually and then loop through the entire range, even if its time consuming?

Here is the code i got from trying to manually record and get it to loop but couldn't figure out the loop part.

```
Sub Hyperlink()

    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Delete
    Range("G2:G1054").Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        Range("S2:S1054"), TextToDisplay:= _
        Range("V2:V1054")

End Sub
```

As an additional comment, the text to displays aren't unique, but they are not all the same, likewise for the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a loop:

```vb
Sub Hyperlink()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, rngLinks As Range, url, txt
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngLinks = ws.Range("G2:G1054")
    rngLinks.Hyperlinks.Delete

    For Each c In rngLinks
        url = c.EntireRow.Columns("S").Value
        txt = c.EntireRow.Columns("V").Value
        If Not IsError(url) And Not IsError(txt) Then
            If Len(url) > 0 And Len(txt) > 0 Then
                ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, _
                   Address:=url, TextToDisplay:=txt
            End If  'not empty
        End If      'not error
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: I really like the ` c.EntireRow.Columns(...)` approach. It's cleaner than my approach for sure, however mine would be easier to adapt if the ranges aren't perfectly aligned in the same sheet.  Regarding the use of `Activesheet`, I think people looking for an answer like this probably need to be advised against using it just in case the wrong sheet is active when you run the code.

Comment: The only problem with use of `ActiveSheet` is when it's used *implicitly* without calling it out.  It's perfectly acceptable to use it explicitly IMO.   The key is the everything your code does is done *intentionally* and not accidentally.

Comment: I tried running this version but it ran into an error, saying Run-time Error '13', Type mismatch. When checking debut it pointed at the second block of code, from ws.Hyperlinks to TextToDisplay. Might be related to the documentation saying that TextToDisplay argument must be a string.

Comment: Works for me if valid URL and "text to display" values are in Cols S and V.  It will fail if either are empty on any given row.

Comment: So if there are any cells that don't have a valid url it will break? Currently because of the way the linking is set up it will sometimes refer to a cell with a #Value! error, is there a workaround for having them or do i just try to run after removing all of these?

Comment: I've run it after deleting all the error cells. It ran fine, however it set all the links to the location of the file itself, not the contents of the cell.

Comment: See edits above

Comment: Thank you, updated version works perfectly and correctly set all the hyperlinks. I'll just run it a few more times to make sure the other data sets are set properly. Once again thank you, saved me my sanity from setting everything manually.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an altered version of the output of the macro recorder. The issue here is that `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add` works with one single cell at a time, so you can't give it a range with multiple cells.

Instead, you'll need to use a loop. For example:

```vb
Sub Hyperlink()

    'Define your workbook variable
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'Or use Workbooks("<YourWorkbookName>")
    
    'Define your worksheet variable
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Replace with your sheet name
    
    'Define your ranges
    Dim DestinationRange As Range
    Set DestinationRange = ws.Range("G2:G1054")
       
    Dim AddressRange As Range
    Set AddressRange = ws.Range("S2:S1054")
    
    Dim TextToDiplayRange As Range
    Set TextToDiplayRange = ws.Range("V2:V1054")
        
    'Apply hyperlinks to one cell at a time.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To DestinationRange.Cells.Count
           
        ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=DestinationRange.Cells(i, 1), _
            Address:=AddressRange.Cells(i, 1).Value2, _
            TextToDisplay:=TextToDiplayRange.Cells(i, 1).Value2
            
    Next

End Sub
```

Note that you don't need to delete previous hyperlinks if you are going to overwrite them anyway.

Comment: Tried running this version but it ran into Run-time Error '5', Invalid procedure call or argument. Debug showed it being related to the ws.Hyperlinks section

Comment: @JuanP - as discussed in the other thread, this can occur when a value in the range with "URL addresses" or "Text to display" is empty or invalid. You can always add some checks with an [if-statement](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/else-if-statement) to look at the values before adding the link to prevent this or use [On Error Resume Next](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/on-error-resume-next-goto-0/) if you want to ignore those errors.